# How to get featured image from post

Tags: php, wordpress, function

Currently working on a `blog site` using `WordPress`.
what I'm trying to do is I want to call a functions when a **post is publish for a first time not on update of post** and try to retrieve featured `image url` that is attached to that post.
I want to know which hook I have to call and how to do that. Do I have to add plugins?.

Comment: see this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [`save_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) hook can be used for this purpose it has a third parameter
>   `$update` which can be used to determine just to check it is new or
>   existing.

```
/**
 * Save post metadata when a post is saved.
 *
 * @param int $post_id The post ID.
 * @param post $post The post object.
 * @param bool $update Whether this is an existing post being updated or not.
 */
function save_post_first_time($post_id, $post, $update)
{
    //check for revision
    if (wp_is_post_revision($post_id))
        return;
    if (!$update)
    {
        // it's a new post
        //getting post featured image ID
        $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id);
        $imageSRC = wp_get_attachment_image_src($post_thumbnail_id, 'thumbnail');
    }
    else
    {
        // it's an existing post
    }
}

add_action('save_post', 'save_post_first_time', 10, 3);
```

Reference:

- [save_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post)
- [the_post_thumbnail_url](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail_url)
- [get_post_thumbnail_id](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_thumbnail_id)

Hope this helps!

Comment: When I add this in theme functions.php file of my used theme , Set featured image not working properly. When I upload the file it get some error uploading file.

Comment: pls copy paste your error, because I just tested my code it is working perfectly.

Comment: I didn't get any error log just text in my admin panel while uploading image

"An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later."
But when I remove the functions it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    the_post_thumbnail();
}
```

if you need the post featued image URL use the below code

```
<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>

<img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="" />
```

If you need to change the size, replace "single-post-thumbnail" with thumbnail, medium, large, full